# Web apps to make your answers awesomer!

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality

What kind of web apps can you use to make your answers awesomer?

This includes things like:

- Interactive regex tester
- Pastebin, online REPL/IDE, image hosting
- Visual aids to generate charts, trees, graphs (i.e. vertices and edges), etc

Comment: I'm not really sure why this is on meta.  You could ask the question on Stack Overflow: "What online tools can I use to help extend programming collaboration?"

Comment: @George: well, if the mods feel like it, they can reverse-migrate this to stackoverflow.com then.

Comment: I like this question ... its not really strictly programming related though you could make an argument for it belonging on web apps ...

Comment: @waffles: my argument for it belonging in meta is that ultimately it's really about improving the quality of your answers. You have a snippet in your answer? Link to online IDE so people can see that it runs and works. You have a regex solution? Prove it by seeing it live in action, so people can see what's matched and what's not, and they can even throw their own input at it. Explaining some concept that can really use visual aids? UML diagrams? Need to layout a graph? etc,etc,etc.

Comment: Sorry ... I should have been more explicit, I think it belongs on either "meta" or the upcoming "web apps" stackexchange. It does not, imho, belong on stack overflow.

Comment: By the way, if others feel that these "bells and whistles" don't really make an answer awesomer, or if visual aids take too much screen space and/or unfairly draws too much attention to a particular answer etc, then feel free to downvote (or better yet, voice your opinion).

Answer (score 10):

I'm not experienced enough in these to know if they're the best, or even recommendable; I can only say that I've used them:

#### Online IDEs

These give a runnable context for snippets in your answer, so people can see that it works and test and/or modify it easily.

- [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) (many languages!)
- [lotrepls.appspot.com](http://lotrepls.appspot.com/) (had to use this for groovy)
- [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) (a rather good edit/test tool, complete with syntax highlighting and smart indentation)
- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (HTML/CSS/JS editor, excellent to demo certain JS libraries e.g. jQuery)

#### Regex

- Editor/tester: [rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/)

  - No lookbehind, no substitution, but otherwise work fine so far
- Editor/tester: [JRX: real-time JavaScript RegExp evaluator](http://www.cuneytyilmaz.com/prog/jrx/#)
- Explainer: [Rick Measham's explain.pl](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?)

  - Not sure if this works perfectly 100% correct, but I've used it occasionally
- Not an app, but [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

#### Visual aids

Never really had to use these, but probably will eventually:

- [yuml.me](http://yuml.me/) (UML diagrams)
- [Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html)

#### Specialized

- [codingbat.com/Authoring](http://codingbat.com/authoring.html#problem)

  - Java only for now, but you can create problems and give your spec through the tests
  - Perhaps more appropriate for asking rather than answering questions

Comment: Just as expected, there are online xpath tester, xslt processor, etc. I'm sure these will come in handy for those who specialize in the technology. I'll let them provide recommendations.

Comment: I forgot that we want to make SEDE/stexdex a tool for teaching SQL, so I guess that should be included. Even if the data may not be be directly relevant for a given question, the technique shown can still be, and seeing it live in action can be helpful.

Comment: To be incorporated later (after further evaluation), suggestion from Peter Ajtai: http://jsfiddle.net/, http://codepad.org/, http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: WolframAlpha is nifty for plotting graphs http://www.wolframalpha.com

Comment: groovy (and even SQL) is available at Ideone

Answer (score 2):

Though I use this for designing actual web sites, http://gomockingbird.com/ definitely has potential to help to visualize things and share them

Comment: Nice site. I hadn't seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

I'll list my favorites

**Regex Tester**

- [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/)

**Information**

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) (for linking that extra information on Hash Tables, CPUs, etc)
- [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/default.aspx) (for all those .NET classes and methods)
- [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/) (for all those java classes and methods).

**Image Hosting**

- <strike>[TinyPic](http://tinypic.com/)</strike> [No longer needed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/)

Comment: I've actually had problems with tinypic "killing" old links or replacing it with new pictures (often very inappropriate ones). Then again that was a long time ago; I haven't really used online image hosting much.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: I use it all the time for my screenshots.

Comment: We now have an official image hosting facility, thanks to imgur: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

Answer (score 0):

#### Stack Overflow

- [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) makes examining and explaining a wide range of compiled languages, though primarily C and C++, very straightforward.
- [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) is *the* explorer for regular expressions. The only downside is it doesn't match HTML open tags except XHTML self-contained tags.

#### General

- Grammarly (Freeware or Paid) or [Microsoft Editor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/microsoft-editor) (requires Microsoft 365 subscription): Fixes grammar mistakes and typos, and suggests replacement word options to make your article look more professional.
- [Draw.io](https://draw.io/) for creating graphs and diagrams.

Comment: It may not mean anything, but it appears slightly conflicting that you would answer this question, and then vote to close it less than 2 hours later.