# Has there ever been an attempt to make "best of" compilations for a particular area?

Tags: discussion

One of the things cool about this type of site is it seems to capture the most common requirements of people learning a topic. Has there ever been an attempt to make "best of" compilations for a particular area? Or is this accomplished by just looking at the most active, highest-scoring questions?

Comment: I don't know about a "best of," but a user who goes by the name polygenelubricants is trying to [write some comprehensive reference articles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62695/permission-to-start-a-series-of-advanced-regex-articles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag FAQs pretty-much do this. Viewing a tag and clicking the **faq** link will show the most linked-to questions in that tag.

Comment: that's exactly what I was hoping to find out... thanks for the tip!