# Is an FAQ (i.e. a collection of questions) considered on topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

I'm referring specifically to this post: [Reference - frequently asked questions about PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo)

It's essentially a collection of questions and then each answer is an answer to one of those questions. To me that clearly doesn't seem an appropriate format for a Stack Overflow question.

If the questions really are FAQs then assumedly they already exist somewhere on Stack Overflow with answers that have been accepted by the community. A collection of links to those questions in the PDO tag wiki would seem to me a more sensible way to compile an FAQ.

But this question has now been closed and reopened twice already, so I'm hesitant to vote to close it again if it's just going to be reopened. So what is the appropriate way to deal with this? Or should it just be left as it is?

Comment: This particular question has already been discussed I think. Can't find the duplicate though. I find them a well intended but ultimately poor approach. Voting to close against that one is the equivalent of saying *"that already has an answer, somewhere, over there....search around a bit"*.

Comment: Related/previous discussion: [PHP Errors Reference question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149743/php-errors-reference-question), consensus being that tag wikis are not [fit for the purpose yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124448/community-wiki-reference-questions), and reference collections are a better interims solution than the **excessive** duplicates in the php tag.