# Should flagging a question for closure prevent close-voting?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close

Back in April, I flagged a post as "not a real question".  The post was subsequently closed and reopened, then closed again and finally just reopened a 2nd time a short time ago.

I still firmly believe the post is not acceptable for SO, so I went to use my recently acquired close vote privilege and was greeted with the following messsage:

[image]

I specifically clicked close and not flag (and figuring I just clicked in error, I tried again and got the same message).

I do understand that, in the new closing system, flagging for closure is treated very much like a close vote (since it throws it to the close vote queue) except no vote is actually recorded.  My issue is why should by flag be counted as a close vote when I never actually voted to close.

Comment: Just curious, what question?

Comment: @RyPeck This is a general question, but this meta post should answer that question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193136/is-an-faq-i-e-a-collection-of-questions-considered-on-topic-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I can see if a person had flagged for closure and then not be able to vote for closure if the question was never closed, but according to the post, the OP had flagged for closure, and the question was subsequently closed and then reopened. Shouldn't the original close flag then no longer count toward future actions at the point of closure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some discussion, a change is being pushed out to allow users that previously flagged for recommend closure to then cast a full close vote, after they've attained the appropriate privilege.  The main justification being that this new privilege supersedes the old and you should be able to exercise that privilege.

As Martijn pointed out in this question's comments and [Shadow in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235295/3), this could lead to questions being put into the close review queue twice by the same user.  However, this theoretically shouldn't happen often, due to the small number of affected users; we'll be monitoring to see if changes need to be made to the queue to prevent this duplication from occurring.

Comment: Sounds like this is a no, but will there be any restrictions right away to prevent duplication, such as "If the post is closed as a result of the flag (and subsequently reopened)", "if your flag is rejected", or "only if the flag is still active". Or will these be the types of things you are monitoring for?

Comment: We'll keep an eye on this, @psubsee2003, but keep in mind that this is not particularly easy to abuse as you have to change your privilege level in order to do so. We may also start aging close flags in the future, which would tend to increase the chance that a given flag gets ignored and you have to earn 3K to get attention.