# Close flag turned into close vote shown as pending review in flagged posts

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

Link to question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063558/does-google-ocr-create-html-code-from-a-pdf for closure when my rep was below 3k. As I crossed the line, the flag transmuted into a close vote, due to some kind of voodoo spell, I presume.

The funny thing is that it is still listed as "waiting for review" under "moderator attention flags". Is this a bug? Or is this such a rare event there is no need to bother? :-)

BTW, the question is really low quality, but for some reason (maybe I'm buggering the gods with all this), it has only my close vote so far... :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it didn't. Another user cast a close vote on the question for a different reason. It has nothing to do with your recommend closure flag, which is still pending, as is the Close Votes review item.

Previous flags do not get automatically changed to close votes when you pass 3,000 reputation.

Comment: Interestingly, the system blocks me from voting to close it, saying "You flagged this question for closure Aug 5 at 17:14". So I thought it was a vote now. Thanks.

Comment: Related to that: [Should flagging a question for closure prevent close-voting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193146/should-flagging-a-question-for-closure-prevent-close-voting)