# If I flagged a question will I ever be able to vote to close it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close

I've recently gained the close voting privilege. I was looking over my flag history for questions I'd flagged which both didn't get closed and didn't get fixed, and I've found a few. The flags were both marked as helpful and unhelpful.

But when I go to those questions I can't vote to close them as it says "You have already flagged this question for closure". Does this mean I will never be able to vote to close on these questions again? If so why?

If this is the case it seems quite problematic to me because it means a mod can unilaterally take away my voting rights on those questions with no explanation. I have no problem with mods insta-closing or reopening, as those actions can be reverted later on. I also have no expectation that my intuitions as to what is too broad or opinion-based line up with the community's consensus either - that's what makes the voting system good because it does take agreement to close these questions when each person can only get 20% there. But if I'm prevented from voting because I flagged in the past then I can't put my 20% opinion out there (even if sometimes it's going to be the only vote) - it will forever be 0%.

Comment: Flags to close are handled by the community via the closing review queue, not by diamond moderators anymore. You already sent the post to the review queue, allowing you to vote now would give you a second vote, effectively.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193146/should-flagging-a-question-for-closure-prevent-close-voting (not marking as dupe since this one here is discussion, while the other is a bug report)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: The [meta-tag:status-by-design] shows us what the devs think about it, and I agree with Anna's answer there. That, for me, effectively answers this post too.

Comment: @Martijn I would have happily voted to close if I could put the hammer aside. But using the binding vote feels wrong in case it's not 100% dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you explain how voting now would give me a second vote when my flag was not counted as a vote? Especially if the flag was rejected?

Comment: @curiousdannii: see the comment thread on Anna's answer, I am not going to repeat that discussion here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've read the comment thread and it doesn't explain why she thinks it's double voting. Actually I may ask a second question about that.