# Request for comments... Series of tightly related questions, which form a tutorial in their entirety

Tags: discussion, self-answer

During a project I had to delve into the QtCreator code to get a deeper understanding on how to write plugins. It was quite a hard work, since the documentation within the QtCreator code is not the best. My best resource was an ancient pdf, which described the plugin development for QtCreator 1. Most of the code did not even compile for QtCreator 2 anymore.

Now I would hate to see my efforts to learn all this go to waste. What I could easily do is to write a new pdf for QtCreator 2. But this would also age and be worthless in a few months.

So my idea is to create this tutorial on SO. Here is an example question:
[How do I add my own options page to the QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633006/how-do-i-add-my-own-options-page-to-the-qtcreator)

If this is accepted in general, I would add further questions:

- How do I add a navigation panel to the QtCreator
- How do I add an editor to the QtCreator
- How do I add....

Then I'd like to cross link between the questions. The advantage is, that others could improve the questions and further comments/answers could be added to keep it up-to-date with changing QtCreator versions.

Does anyone see a problem with the above question/answer? My plan? Comments?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62695/permission-to-start-a-series-of-advanced-regex-articles

Comment: *sigh* the 'duplicate' answer trap. Strangely much **much** easier to fall into it than in main. :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is entirely fine to post a question and its answer at the same time, as you have done in your linked example.

This is acceptable and supported directly in the ask a question page.

However, each question should stand on its own - it should be fully answerable without relying on other posts. Which makes a tutorial series something problematic.

You can link to other questions directly or in comments, but there is no support for a "table of contents" as such - however, to the right of the question you will fined "Linked" and "Related" questions.

In summary - so long as the questions are suitable questions for Stack Overflow and stand on their own, and both they and their answers are of high quality, I see no issue.

Comment: Thanks, thought so. But wanted to make sure. :-) Especially about the cross link part.

Comment: @Greenflow - So long as you don't start/end the posts with a long list of links...

Comment: I did a [similar thing with a SQL question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) - I wanted a nice in-depth article to be able to link to when anwering simple questions that popped up on a regular basis. Be aware though, your Q&A may well get closed like mine did (there are currently three re-open votes inlcuding mine) but also 4 delete votes, which boggle me. I don't understand why folks would want to delete it.

Comment: @Fluffeh: And the meta effect stikes again. Re-opened.

Comment: @Meta (especially the folks who voted to re-open) Thankyou! Wasn't really anticipating it, but really glad that it won't get deleted as I think it really is a great resource to link to for a more detailed explanation of how SQL works - even if only for myself when psoting answers to common questions. Thank you again guys!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you put the tutorial somewhere else (your own web site, google docs, whatever) and then when you see questions that you've taken care of, answer something like this:

As I explain in section X of my Y tutorial, this is taken care of with a call to A and then B.

Then some code and a short explanation. Make part of the first sentence a link - to the whole tutorial, or to the right section if you can. Do not provide only the link - the answer should answer the question. But it can be a shortened version and people can go to the tutorial for all the details, the error checking, the diagrams and so on.

And if people aren't asking the questions, you can do the ask-and-answer but be careful. Most people find composing those questions (and still having them be good questions) to be quite hard.