# How can I write an article on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, article

I have prepared a very nice article for sending text messages and want to publish it here on Stack Exchange. How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission to start a series of advanced regex articles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62695/permission-to-start-a-series-of-advanced-regex-articles)

Comment: @gnat, that's a dangerous duplicate suggestion to be making, given that the questions derived from that question were all accepted and well recieved by the community. Were trying to convince the user that we *don't* want random articles on *any* of our sites.

Comment: I feel that this question applies equally to all stack exchange sites, regardless. I have suggested an edit to cover Stack Exchange for future "can I blog, here?" questions.

Comment: @Gnemlock can't tell about all sites but SO specifically has a very detailed and accurate meta guidance on these matters: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165/839601)

Comment: Visit http://stackexchange.com/tour & https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: This thread is in serious need for an update. Notice comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416872).

Answer (score 15):

You don't. Stack Exchange sites are not blogs.

If you can formulate your article as a question which is not too broad, or opinion based, and a subsequent answer, you could post it here, but I highly doubt if you can rewrite it that far.

A blog might be more suitable for your article.

Comment: How to write blog here? can you assists me

Comment: Sorry, no. Such advice is off-topic here. Just Google your question and you will find a lot of information.

Comment: @TechnologyDiagnostic - Stack Exchange websites do not have "blog" capabilities at this time.

Comment: any update? https://stackoverflow.com/teams/features/articles

Answer (score 9):

Short answer; you don't.

---

Stack Exchange is a series of question and answer sites; as such, it is not the appropriate place to simply post articles we have created on a particular topic.

We can certainly publish material we have written without somebody *else* asking about it, but we should/must also ensure that:

- We are formatting the content as a quality question and answer, and *not* a "how-to".
- We are posting a question that would be useful to other users.
- We are posting a question/answer that is of *quality* format, with an emphasis on "straight to the point", and direct, definitive answers over discussion-orientated ones.
- We are posting the content on a site where the content falls *within* the scope of both Stack Exchange, and what that site considers to be on-topic.

---

It is next to impossible to tell if your article would be appropriate *anywhere*, but it is certainly inappropriate for Stack Overflow (a programming-focused site). I can easily speculate that anything written as an *article* would still require extensive format to be left open, let alone received well. I would recommend looking for a *blogging* platform for self-publishing articles.

Comment: can i post a blog here on stack overflow instead of an article

Comment: @TechnologyDiagnostic what don't you get about the multiple "no"s you've already had?

Comment: @TechnologyDiagnostic, safest bet is to assume you can not post your content *at all* across the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: thisresponse really make sense

Comment: @TechnologyDiagnostic Nope; What you want to do is not possible.

Comment: any update? https://stackoverflow.com/teams/features/articles

Answer (score 2):

Articles are now available for Stack Overflow for Teams: see
https://stackoverflow.com/teams/features/articles